# Setting a control's ID in code behind for use in a validation control

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

How can I use validation controls within server controls? The issue that I have is that by default if I do something like this:

```
private TextBox _textbox;
RequiredFieldValidator _validator;

protected override void OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _textbox= new TextBox {ID = "test"};
    _validator = new RequiredFieldValidator{ControlToValidate = _textbox.ID};
}

protected override void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Add(_textbox);
    this.Controls.Add(_validator);
}
```

Then it works fine but because I've set the ID in code behind the textbox has an ID of test in the actual generated HTML (instead of ctl1_ctl2_test or or something.) This means that if I use the control twice on the same page then I get an error. If I don't set an ID then it is null and the validator can't find the control.

Any help would be great,

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Why would you want to use the same control twice in a page? Using the same control twice is like you being in two places at the same time. Do not do. Quantum entanglement hasn't reached .Net yet. Create a new control.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Are you trying to use the RequiredFieldValidator twice(for 2 differente controls) in your page?

Comment: Have you tried to set the ControlToValidate property in a later stage of the page's lifecycle, f.e. in load or prerender? @Sani: I assume this is a Custom- or UserControl and this control is used multiple times on the page.

Comment: I've tried getting it OnPreRender and that doesn't work, but I'm facing another issue where I 've got a Repeater which has various controls added to its ItemTemplate. It needs to use FindControl to reference the controls in its ItemDataBound event but again I can't set a unique ID for them.

Comment: Sani: To clarify, it is just code re-use. I'm talking about creating two instances of the same control not trying to insert the same control in to two places in the control hierarchy (Which I believe is impossible to make .NET do, it would just duplicate it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `INamingContainer` to the list of interfaces implemented by your server control:

```
public class RequiredTextBox : Control, INamingContainer
```

Now the ID of the child `TextBox` will be scoped by the ID of the server control, thus avoiding ID conflicts.